# How to implement a Generic method

Tags: java, generics

I need to implement the method as generic. How to do it ?

```
public SelectItem[] criarFiltroSexo(Sexo[] tp){
SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
       for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
           options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
       }  
       return options;  
}
```

I have to implement more methods like this and I need to replicate for each different entity.So I have a lot of methods criarFiltroxxx

I would like to implement something like this :

```
public <E> criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp){
        SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
            options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
        }  
         return options;
    }
```

*But I got error message : return type of method is missing.....*

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your code is perfectly typesafe now. Where do you want generics applied?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have to implement more methods like this and I need to replicate for each different entity.So I have a lot of methods criarFiltroxxx

Comment: @Ivan Koblik The link is useful for me. thanks. But How I implement generics with tp[i].getID() for example ?

Comment: You need to work on the text of your question. Did you think it was clear from it that you need to generify along the filter type axis? That's not how you ask a question in public.

Comment: @Al2x: do all those classes have a common base class?

Comment: If your arguments all have the same methods (getId() and getDescricao()), you don't need to use generics. You can create an interface instead and use it instead of Sexo.

Comment: @IvanKoblik Tutorial has been updated ;) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: yes. they do @Joachim Sauer

Comment: I would like to do something like this : public <E> criarFiltrogenerico(<T>[] tp){
  SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
  for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
            options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
        }  
   return options;
 }

Comment: But I got return type of method is missing

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have changed my question. Would you please check if its unclear ?

Comment: Yes, much better now. As the compiler says, return type is missing, so add it: it's `SelectItem[]`. However, I don't see you relying on the generic type in the implementation. Why not just have `criarXxxFiltro(Object[] array)`? Or an appropriate superclass which declares `getId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I got error message : return type of method is missing.....

In the line:

```
public <E> criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp) {
```

What you have is `public` keyword, `<E>` type variable and `criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp)` method name and parameters.

Naturally, you lack the return type. Add it:

```
public <E> RETURN-TYPE-HERE criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp) {
```

So this would work:

```
public <E> SelectItem[] criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp) {
        SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
            options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
        }  
        return options;
}
```

The caveat is that the type `E` must have the `getId()` and `getDescricao()` methods. If you have a parent class/interface with those methods, say `ParentItem` (where `Sexo extends ParentItem` or `Sexo implements ParentItem`), you should use:

```
public <E extends ParentItem> SelectItem[] criarFiltrogenerico(E[] tp) {
```

Comment: I got error : The method getDescricao() is undefined for the type E. The method getId is undefined for the type E.

Comment: Yeah, I just added that observation. Check the last part: *"The caveat is that the type `E`..."*.

Comment: this method was implemented in my bean named Pessoa. I cant extend ParentItem thats because I need to call this method passing as parameter another entity like Sexo etc...

Comment: Does `Sexo` extend any class or implement any interface?

Comment: Sexo does not extend any class and does not implement any interface. Sexo is an enum.

Comment: You'll either have to create an interface and make everyone you will use in that method (like `Sexo`) implement it OR, just to add as a possibility, you can use reflection (but this would throw a runtime error if a class without `getId()` and `getDescricao()` was given as parameter) .

Comment: @Al2x: then how do you know that `E` has the methods `.getId()` and `.getDescricao()`?

Comment: @newacct .getID and .getDescricao always will have both that properties enum. its a convention defined by the project

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are two ways you could approach this problem without having to rewrite the code for every type:

1. You use Generics. This would mean having the entire object which includes your `criarFiltroSexo(...)` function and creating one object for each class you want to use it with. If `criarFiltroSexo` is in a class called `DoStuff` and `Sexo` extends `ParentClass` (as do all the other classes that you want to use that function with) for example, you would implement it like this:

   ```
   public class DoStuff<T extends ParentClass> {
       //...
       public SelectItem[] criarFiltroSexo(T[] tp){
           SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
           for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
               options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
           }  
           return options;  
       }
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Use inheritance instead. Then your function would look like this:

   ```
   public SelectItem[] criarFiltroSexo(ParentClass[] tp){
       SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
       for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
           options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(),tp[i].getDescricao());  
       }
       return options;  
   }
   ```

   Now you can call that with arrays of everything that extends `ParentClass`, e.g. `Sexo[] sexos = new Sexo[10]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that has the methods you need to use:

```
interface HasIdAndDescricao {
    int getId();
    String getDescricao();
}
```

Add that interface to the classes you want to use with the method:

```
class Sexo implements HasIdAndDescricao {
    // no change required
}
```

Bound the generic to the interface:

```
public <T extends HasId> SelectItem[] criarFiltrogenerico(T[] tp){
    SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[tp.length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {  
        options[i] = new SelectItem(tp[i].getId(), tp[i].getDescricao());  
    }  
    return options;
}
```

You may want to use a varargs parameter instead, without changing the method body:

```
public <T extends HasId> SelectItem[] criarFiltrogenerico(T... tp){
    // same body
}
```